# How to grap the content between <span class="attribute first">AUTHOR: </span>Stepfen King

Tags: xpath

I have the following source:

```
<p class="byline"><span class="attribute first">AUTHOR: </span>Stephen Butts<span class="attribute">DATE: </span><span class="monthText" style="margin-right:4px;">MAY</span>2015<span class="attribute">SUBJECT: </span>Options</p>
```

I want to use the XPath to grap the text/content of the AUTH: Stephen King. I've tried using the following but it doesn't work:

```
authors = tree.xpath('//span[@class="attribute first"]/text()', namespaces=ns)
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a text of `p`, but not `span`. Try:

```
//p[@class="byline"]/text()[2]
```

or

```
//span[@class="attribute first"]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```